# What's the easiest way to implement division in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, relational-division

I'm putting together a simple cooking application that holds recipes in an SQLite database. I have three tables right now: Recipes, Ingredients, Recipe_Ingredients

```
* Recipes
-------------------
name,
-------------------
Lentil Soup
Egg Drop Soup


* Ingredients
-------------------
name,
-------------------
Lentils
Chicken Broth
Tomato
Egg
Onion


* Recipe_Ingredients
-------------------
recipe, ingredient
-------------------
Lentil Soup, Lentils
Lentil Soup, Chicken Broth
Lentil Soup, Tomato
Egg Drop Soup, Egg
Egg Drop Soup, Chicken Broth,   
Egg Drop Soup, Onion
```

I want my application to be able to return recipes based on the ingredients I have available. Something like: "show me all recipes that include both Chicken Broth and Egg".

My SQL is a bit rusty, however, it seems like I would want to use SQL division to essentially divide out all recipes that include both of these ingredients.

Can anyone provide an easy SQL division implementation that SQLite supports?

Comment: I would see if you can work out something similar using the [INTERSECT Operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/intersect.php) because I don't believe SQLLite has this otherwise natively.... Here's an example query but I didn't test it just as an example at least but it might work: https://pastebin.com/iFgUsCsF

Answer (score 1):

A version with subqueries

```
select r.name
from Recipes r
where exist (select * from Recipe_Ingredients ri where ri.recipe=r.name and ri.ingredient="Chicken Broth")
  and exist (select * from Recipe_Ingredients ri where ri.recipe=r.name and ri.ingredient="Egg")
```

A version with an aggegate

```
select
    recipe,
    sum(case when ingredient="Chicken Broth" or ingredient="Egg" then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from Recipe_Ingredients
group by recipe
having cnt=2
```

A version with temp-tables

```
with
i1 as (select recipe from Recipe_Ingredients where ingredient="Chicken Broth"),
i2 as (select recipe from Recipe_Ingredients where ingredient="Egg")
select r.name from Recipes r
join i1 on r.name=i1.recipe
join i2 on r.name=i2.recipe
```